# subsequence is bounded is the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to think about if we have a subsequence that is bounded, when is the overall sequence also bounded:

I've shown this isn't always true, for example $(-1)^{n}$ the subsequences converge and are bounded, but the overall sequence isn't.

A few other examples I thought of but I'm not sure on:

$a_{2}, a_{3}, \dots , a_{n+1}, \dots$ is bounded then is $(a_{n})$ bounded?

$a_{3}, a_{4}, \dots , a_{n+2}, \dots$ is bounded then is $(a_{n})$ bounded?

$a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}, \dots , a_{N+n}, \dots$ is bounded then is $(a_{n})$ bounded?

I think that the third statement is true, but the first two statements are false? I'm thinking this because the third statement has "chopped off" a finite amount of terms. Whereas the first two statements only "chop off" the first term and first two terms respectively.

Thanks.

Comment: Right : so if you leave finitely many terms out, that is bounded, but if you leave out infinitely many terms, what's left out need not be bounded, right? That suggests the answer.

Comment: "*I think that the third statement is true, but the first two statements are false?*"  Uhm... if you let $N=1$ or let $N=2$... isn't the third statement just the general case for the first and second statements?  Chopping off the first term is chopping off a finite number of terms... namely $1$ which is a finite number.

Comment: @JMoravitz good point. Hmm I'm not sure then apart from the fact the third statement is just more general.

Comment: they are all true, if $a_n$ is bounded by $c$ for all $n>N$, take a new bound bound $c' = max\{c, a_1, ... , a_N\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $N\in\mathbb N$, then a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded if and only if the sequence $(a_{N+n})_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ is bounded. That's so because if $M$ is an upper bound of $\{\lvert a_N\rvert,\lvert a_{N+1}\rvert,\ldots\}$, then $M+\max\{\lvert a_1\rvert,\lvert a_2\rvert,\ldots,\lvert a_{N-1}\rvert\}$ is an upper bound of $\{\lvert a_n\rvert\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.